# bazel timeout = moderate doesn't seem to work

Tags: bazel

I tried using 
timeout = moderate, 
in one of my cc_test build rules but when I ran the test I got:

ERROR: /home/miennaco/peloton-tech-code/vehicle/tda2/updater/BUILD:66:15: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/miennaco/peloton-tech-code/vehicle/tda2/updater/BUILD", line 64
                cc_test(name = "som_updater_lib_test", tim..., <3 more arguments>)
        File "/home/miennaco/peloton-tech-code/vehicle/tda2/updater/BUILD", line 66, in cc_test
                moderate
name 'moderate' is not defined

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You want `timeout = "moderate"` instead of `timeout = moderate`. `moderate` is not a keyword.